# Split text into similar chunks but only right after "/>"

Tags: python, html, arrays, string

I'm trying to split an `HTML` file into chunks of at most 5000 bytes (to fit it to the AWS translate).

Assuming a character can be at most 78 bytes big, I've used a simple function that splits text into chunks of 600 characters length.

```
def split_text_to_chunks(text, chunk_length):
    return [text[i:i + chunk_length] for i in range(0, len(text), chunk_length)]

chunks = split_text_to_chunks(HTML,600)
```

This works but there is a problem that AWS translate doesn't like when the text is split in the middle of the HTML tag.

So that means I can split the `HTML` only right after `/>`.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: *"Assuming a character can be at most 78 bytes big"* - ...huh?

Comment: Also, why keep the HMTL at all? Would it not make sense to just send the plain text for translation?

Comment: @Tomalak I work with Korean texts and the biggest character I found was 78 bytes.

Comment: @Tomalak I need to keep the HTML structure.

Comment: Maybe Django's [`_truncate_html`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ecf87ad513fd8af6e4a6093ed918723a7d88d5ca/django/utils/text.py#L151) is useful here.

Comment: @Milano Curious. What encoding are you working with? Which character are we talking about?

Comment: Shouldn't the closing tags be any of </some string>?
Then you should use regular expressions to split the strings

Comment: @Tomalak Sorry, it's 76. `>>> sys.getsizeof('는')
76`

Comment: @Milano getsizeof will not give the size in bytes for the character, it is the memory size of the string object.

Comment: That's the size of the Python string object, that's not the size of the character. `len('는'.encode('utf8'))` is 3 (bytes). In UTF-16 it's 4 bytes. It depends on the encoding, but 76 is not it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to convert your HTML into a "tokenized" set of tags and text. You can stream these results to build a more intelligent chunking process that preserves full tag declarations:

```
import bs4, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
html = "<html>\n\t<div class='test' data-id='111'>\n\t\t<div class='test'>this is some text</div>\n\t\t<p>this is a p text tag</p>\n\t</div>\n</html>"
def get_blocks(s):
   def tokenize(d):
      if isinstance(d, bs4.element.NavigableString):
         yield (str(d), False)
      else:
         yield (f'<{d.name}>' if not d.attrs else '<{} {}>'.format(d.name, ' '.join('{}="{}"'.format(a, b if isinstance(b, str) else ' '.join(b)) for a, b in d.attrs.items())), True)
         yield from [j for k in getattr(d, 'contents', []) for j in tokenize(k)]
         yield (f'</{d.name}>', True)
   yield from tokenize(soup(s, 'html.parser').contents[0])

def get_chunks(html, chunk = 600):
   c, l = '', 0
   for a, b in get_blocks(html):
      if (_l:=len(a)) + l <= chunk:
         c += a
         l += _l
      elif b:
         yield c
         c, l = a, _l
      else:
         if (i:=[j for j, k in enumerate(a) if k in {' ', '.', '\b'}]):
            if (m:=[j for j in i if j + l <= chunk]):
               yield c + a[:(_m:=max(m))+1]
               a, i, l = a[_m+1:], [j for j, k in enumerate(a[_m+1:]) if k in [' ', '.', '\b']], 0
            else:
               yield c
            while i:
               if (m:=[j for j in i if j <= chunk]):
                   yield a[:(_m:=max(m)+1)]
                   a, i = a[_m+1:], [j for j, k in enumerate(a[_m+1:]) if k in [' ', '.', '\b']]
               else:
                   yield a
                   i = []
         else:
            yield c
            yield a
         c, l = '', 0
   yield from ([c] if c else [])

print(list(get_chunks(html, 100)))
```

Output:

```py
['<html>\n<div class="test" data-id="111">\n<div class="test">this is some text</div>\n<p>this is a p ', 'text ', '</p>\n</div>\n</html>']
```

Comment: @Ajax1234 Very nice, thanks. Can this be modified to allow splitting only right after the tag's end or after the beginning (doesn't matter if it's opening or closing tag)? For example: <p>HEREThis is some textHERE</p>HEREAnd this is also a textHERE<div>... The reason is that when  you split "this is a p tex" / "t tag" - the translation will be corrupted.

Comment: @Milano What if the content between the tags is greater than 600 characters? Is that a possibility in your HTML samples? For example, if you have `<p>[600 characters here]</p>`,  `[600 characters here]` would have to be split at some index.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Yes, that would be a problem. I'd say that then - space or dot or regex \b would be a way to go. It's not ideal but much more reliable.

Comment: @Milano Just to confirm, `<p>[600 characters here]</p>` would become `<p>[...x characters].`, ` `[...x1 characters]</p>`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Yes, the point is, if not possible to split the HTML at the beginning or the end of the tag, split it anywhere where space, dot or \b is.

Comment: @Milano Ah, I see, please see my recent edit.